# AVPlayer - toggle between fullscreen

Tags: ios, avfoundation, fullscreen, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a tableview where one of the cells houses a view on which AVPlayer renders a video. Works fine. What I'd like to do is allow the user to rotate the device and have the AVPlayer then render to another fullscreen view. Any pointers on how to do this?

I've successfully added the AVPlayer's CALayer as a sublayer to the fullscreen view, but as soon as I do that the AVPlayer stops playing and I cannot start it up again. I get no notifications regarding its state, and no errors.

I would appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by simply parenting the view (that contains the view with the AVPlayerLayer) to another full screen view and then rotating/scaling it to full screen. No need to worry about multiple AVPlayers etc as Matt mentions in his comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have MoviePlayerVC that adds AVPlayerLayer as a sublayer, and it is a child view controller of MainVC.

**Setup**

```
window.rootViewController = mainVC;
[mainVC ftg_addChildVC:moviePlayerVC]; // Using container view controller
```

There are 3 ways to enable full screen mode

- Remove moviePlayerVC and then present it

  [moviePlayerVC ftg_removeFromParentVC];
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // This make it on another run loop
  [mainVC presentViewController:moviePlayerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
              });

This is not so fast and smooth as the window approach

- Add moviePlayerVC to the keyWindow
- Add moviePlayerVC to a new window (see [FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX))

**Full screen**

```
[moviePlayerVC ftg_removeFromParentVC];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = moviePlayerVC;
```

**Embedded**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = mainVC;
[mainVC ftg_addChildVC:moviePlayerVC];
```